# Do I need a US Visa even if I am only transiting? I'm from the caribbean

Tags: visas, usa, transit, spain

I am traveling to Spain and I have to pass through the US, would I need to get a visa and if so can I get it on the spot (transit visa)? If yes, how long would this process take? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the internet, where TYPING IN CAPS is considered shouting. Please don't do that. Also I'd recommend reading the [help] on questions for this site. Thanks!

Comment: I wish whoever upvoted this would explain their reasoning.